# Click li element JavaScript Programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, click, html-lists

Click li element "**Last 30 days**" programmatically (console)

```
<div class="ranges">
      <ul>
        <li>Today</li>
        <li >Yesterday</li> 
        <li>Last 7 days</li>
        <li>Last 30 days</li>
        <li class="">This month</li>
        <li>Custom Range</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I tried many way but failed

Like.

```
$('#Last 30 days').trigger('click');
$('#Last 30 days').click();
```

I'm new in JavaScript Please help me

Comment: What's supposed to happen on click?

Comment: on Li click date range is getting updated

Comment: Where do you define that click listener?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trigger the click based on HTML inside.

```js
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.ranges li');

listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
     alert(`${event.currentTarget.innerHTML} item was click`);
  });
  if (item.innerHTML.indexOf('Last 30 days') != -1) {
      item.click();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="ranges">
    <ul>
      <li>Today</li>
      <li>Yesterday</li> 
      <li>Last 7 days</li>
      <li>Last 30 days</li>
      <li>This month</li>
      <li>Custom Range</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have here looks like jQuery (or something modeled on jQuery) — not pure, natural JavaScript. I mention this just for completeness and for proper tagging.

That said, and assuming that you actually have jQuery loaded, this is failing because your selectors aren't matching anything. `$('#...')` matches DOM elements by ID. You don't have any IDs. This would work:

```
<div class="ranges">
  <ul>
    <li>Today</li>
    <li >Yesterday</li> 
    <li>Last 7 days</li>
    <li id="target">Last 30 days</li>
    <li class="">This month</li>
    <li>Custom Range</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  $('#target').click();
</script>
```

CSS does not address elements by content, and neither does jQuery. You could find a way to implement it, but it would be horribly inefficient (which is why it's not built in). If you have the option, it's better just to identify each `<li>`.

You can also target by class: `$('.classname')`. But while targeting by ID will typically only hit one element, targeting by class will hit all matching elements.

I also note that you don't appear to have any actions attached to the `click` event on the `<li>` elements, so I'm not sure that you would notice whether the click event is successful, unless there's more to your situation than you've described.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
myLiElement.click();
```

```js
myLiElement.click();

// this is for TEST
function clicked() { console.log('clicked!') }
```

```html
<div class="ranges">
  <ul>
    <li>Today</li>
    <li>Yesterday</li>
    <li>Last 7 days</li>
    <li id="myLiElement" onclick="clicked()">Last 30 days</li>
    <li class="">This month</li>
    <li>Custom Range</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```